Exercise about entropy
I solved the following problem, but I still have some doubts:
The problem: "Two equal quantities of water at temperatures $T_1$ and $T_2$ respectively, with a mass $m$ and specific heat $c$, are mixed under adiabatic conditions and reach thermal equilibrion. Calculate the change in entropy $\Delta S$"
I know that:
$$\Delta S = \int_{T_0}^{T_1} \dfrac{dQ}{T}$$
We have
$\hspace{0,8cm}dQ = mc \hspace{0,1cm}dT \hspace{0,2cm}$ and $\hspace{0,2cm}Q_1=-Q_2 \Longrightarrow mc(T_\text{eq}-T_1)=-mc(T_\text{eq}-T_2) \Longrightarrow T_\text{eq}= \dfrac{T_1+T_2}{2}$
The total change in entropy of the system $\Delta S_\text{system}$ is $$\Delta S_\text{system}= \Delta S_1 + \Delta S_2 = \int_{T_1}^{T_\text{eq}} \hspace{0,05cm}\dfrac{mc\hspace{0,1cm}dT}{T} + \int_{T_2}^{T_\text{eq}} \hspace{0,05cm}\dfrac{mc\hspace{0,1cm}dT}{T} = mc \left(\int_{T_1}^{T_\text{eq}}\dfrac{dT}{T} + \int_{T_2}^{T_\text{eq}}\dfrac{dT}{T} \right) $$
$$= mc \left(\ln \left(\dfrac{T_\text{eq} }{T_1} \right) + \ln \left(\dfrac{T_\text{eq} }{T_2} \right) \right) = mc \ln \left(\dfrac{T_\text{eq}^2}{T_1T_2} \right) = mc \ln \left( \dfrac{(T_1+T_2)^2}{4T_1T_2}\right)$$
My questions:

The above integral formula works only for a reversible process: does this mean that

$\hspace{3,8cm}\Delta S_\text{system}= -\Delta S_\text{surrounding} \hspace{0,2cm}$ so that $\hspace{0,2cm}\Delta S_\text{tot}=0$
But how can this be possible if the system is thermally isulated?

Are there other way to calculate $\Delta S_\text{system}$ that don't revolve around calculus?


The first step is to find the final temperature of the two masses.

Well, since they are equal, I think we should have $$Q_1=-Q_2 \Longrightarrow mc (T_\text{eq}-T_1) = -mc (T_\text{eq}-T_2) \Longrightarrow T_\text{eq} = \dfrac{T_1+T_2}{2}$$

Your solution is correct.

Great! By the way, the equation  $Q_1 = -Q_2$ holds because we assume $\Delta E_\text{int} = 0$ right? And also, let's say che cooling/heating of the two masses is reversible, does that mean that the entopy of the surrounding is $-\ln \left( \dfrac{(T_1+T_2)^2}{4T_1T_2} \right)$ so that the total change of entropy is $0$?

Yes, the change in combined internal energy is zero.  For the surroundings, the change in entropy is zero.  The total change in entropy for this irreversible process is the same as that of the system > 0.

@ChetMiller Firstly, thanks for all your help. If we say that this transformation is reversible, shouldn't be the total change in entropy $0$?  Or since this is an isolated system we will directly have $\Delta S _\text{syst} = 0$

Welcome Lorenzo! I think it would be nice if you could check here the norms about homework-like questions. There is nothing "wrong" with your question, but following some guidelines could avoid possible headaches. Remember to use the homework tag and avoid to make question whose the answer could be a simple "yes" or "no", like "is this correct?".

The transformation is not reversible.  We can't make it reversible simply by saying that it is reversible.  If you think that you can devise a reversible path between the same end states, let's hear about it.

Oh ok. But does this mean the result is incorrect, since the integral formula only works for reversible cases?

It’s a good question, which has been addressed here before. The mixing is irreversible but can be replaced with a conceptual reversible process in which each quantity of water is brought to the final equilibrium temperature by successive contact with an infinite number of thermal reservoirs. Since entropy is a state variable, the entropy change in the water must be the same.

@Lorenzo No. Entropy is a function of state. The change in entropy of the system is only the difference between the entropies of the initial and final states of the system. So it doesn't matter what path you use. For example, in Joule expansion, the standard technique for finding the entropy change is to consider a reversible process between the initial and final states, even though the actual process is obviously irreversible.

Thanks for your answers. So the only important things are the initial state, final state and the type of transformation since as example all adiabatics (reversibles or not) taking a system from the same initial state to the same final state will have all the same change in entropy right? But reversible processes (which will increase the entropy of a system) will decrease the entropy of the surrounding so that $\Delta S _\text{tot}=0$ if I understood it correctly.

@Chemomechanics  > Each quantity of water is brought to the final equilibrium temperature by successive contact with an infinite number of thermal reservoirs.
Isn't that unnecessary? I thought that it was enough if you could consider the objects in thermal equilibrium in every instant, so even if the 2 objects didn't have the same temperature, by assuming that the heat transfert was really slow you could have gotten a reversible process.

Even infinitesimally slow heat transfer between objects at two different temperatures is irreversible.

Oh so the only case in which a transformation is reversible is when the 2 objects are in fact in thermal equilibrium? And as example, in an ideal Carnot engine there would be those infinite resevoirs, but the only important ones are the hotter  and the coldest right?

Heat transfer in the Carnot engine occurs at only two fixed temperatures, so only two reservoirs are required. There’s no mixing or temperature equilibration (or irreversibility at all) in the Carnot engine; a discussion of that point would be better suited to a new question.

$\Delta S_{surr} = 0$ because the system is thermally insulated.
$\Delta S_{sys} > 0$, and your work to calculate it appears correct. The process is thus not reversible: $\Delta S_{universe} = \Delta S_{surr} + \Delta S_{sys} > 0$.
What we have done in using $\Delta S = \int_{}^{}\frac{Q_{rev}}{T}$ is construct a reversible path from our initial conditions to our final conditions, even though that is not the actual path. Imagine taking your colder water, and contacting it with incrementally warmer reservoirs until it has reached the final temperature, and separately doing the same with your warmer water. That is the reversible path over which we have calculated $\Delta S_{sys}$. If our actual process followed that path, $\Delta S_{surr}$ would be $< 0$ and $\Delta S_{universe}$ would be zero.
However, that is not the actual path that is followed in the process. In the actual path, the water is mixed irreversibly. $S_{sys}$ is a state property, and is thus the same as if we had followed the reversible path. The difference comes in because in this irreversible process, instead of exchanging heat with reservoirs in the surroundings and making $\Delta S_{surr}$ negative, the system is now insulated, making $\Delta S_{surr} = 0$.
